# How to Get MEPSystemClassification enum culture name with the Revit API

Tags: c#, revit-api

The RevitAPI  provides  the enum  MEPSystemClassification , in the different language version . The name of the mepSystemClassification value is different .Is there a approach to get the name of mepSystemClassification by the language?

I have tried that by Getting the systemClassification parameter,the value is the culture name .
but sometimes when i get the enum value i may need to compare the name and the enum value is or identical